# Executing a specific function depend on type

Tags: c++

I want to make a function which can handle different kind of things depend on type all in one.

I know Overloading is a nice solution for it. Just like,

```
class C1 {...};
class C2 {...};    
void handle(C1& c1){...}
void handle(C2& c2){...}
```

But there are so many duplicated code in Overloading way since these 2  initialization is the same. That's why I want to wrap them together.

I have some ideas for my purpose. 
For example,

```
class C1 {...};
class C2 {...};

void handle_C1(C1 &c1);
void handle_C2(C2 &c2);

template<typename T>
void handle(T &content){
// Initialization was done here
if (std::is_same(C1, T))
   handle_C1(content);
if (std::is_same(C2, T))
   handle_C2(content);
}
```

A compilation error was found error that **handle_C2 mismatch parameters** because handle_C2 parameter type is C2 when I call

```
C1 c1;
handle_C1<C1>(c1);
```

According to SFINAE in C++, I expect the compile would ignore this substitution failed, but it doesn't.

Is there anyone can give me a advice?

Is the best solution overloading? if it's true, how can I reduce my duplicated code.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to write one function witch takes as arguments different objects and performs various actions with them.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. One function handles different types with corresponding method.

Comment: You can pass handle as a paramter using `std::function` or functors or use inheritance.

Comment: It's actually `is_same_v<T, U>`, not `is_same(T, U)`.  Type traits don't work in this way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems to me you are overthinking the problem. Simply define overloads without the initialization code and define a `handle` function that takes advantage of overload resolution.

```
class C1 {...};
class C2 {...};    
void handle_impl(C1& c1){...} // Remove initialization from your overloads
void handle_impl(C2& c2){...}

template<typename T>
void handle(T &content)
{
    // Initialization is done here

    // Let the compiler resolve overloads for you
    handle_impl(content);
}
```

Comment: It's maybe a useful way. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

When handle() is instantiated with a T, the full body of the function is instantiated. Both of the "if"s and their bodies are compiled.  While you and I know that is_same() is a compile time constant and you may expect the compiler to ignore the impossible case, the way it's used is as a runtime value and the compiler *must* process both ifs and semantically checked "as if" they were both potentially called (even if the optimizer can eliminate one, that's after the validity testing the compiler does.)  You thus end up with code calling handle_C1 and handle_C2, both passed the same type, and one is sure to be invalid and fail to compile.

If you can use c++17, a new feature directly addresses this problem, called "constexpr if" which makes the body of the if get processed (aside from valid statements and syntax) if the constexpr is true:

```
template<typename T>
void handle(T &content){
// Initialization was done here
if constexpr (std::is_same(C1, T))
   handle_C1(content);
else if constexpr (std::is_same(C2, T))
   handle_C2(content);
}
```

If you don't have a c++17 compiler, (or even if you do!) you should consider going back to your original design and simply factor out the initialization from each of the functions and make it a generic helper function.

Comment: You could fix this by combining overloading and templating. Name the `handle_C` functions the same (probably `handle_impl`) and get rid of the `if`, so that your template instantiation will call the correct overload.

Comment: It should be `std::is_same_v<C1, T>` instead.

Comment: With `if constexpr`, the `else` and `else if` branches don't have `constexpr` afterwards.

Comment: @Justin `else if` *can* have `constexpr` afterwards (since `else if` is just `else` followed by a statement that happens to be an `if` statement), but you're right that it doesn't seem to be required (I'm actually a bit surprised by that).

Answer (score 2):

I think in your case overloading is all you need. Simply write another method for you special initialization that handles each class and do your general stuff in the templated version ([online](http://ideone.com/K1G2UC)):

```
void handleSpecial(C1& c1) {
    std::cout << "Handling C1\n";
}
void handleSpecial(C2& c2) {
    std::cout << "Handling C2\n";
}
template <typename T>
void handle(T& content) {
    std::cout << "Doing generell stuff\n";
    handleSpecial(content);
}
```

SFINAE only works before choosing which function to call, which in this case can't happen because the function can be called with any type. Then the whole body will be generated and you get the compiler error, because there's no function `handle_C1` for `C2` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Going through your steps:

If you have multiple classes that are handled the same for many things, but have individual character, then this could call for a base class. E.g. You could have something like:

```
class CBase { ... common features of C1, C2, C3, ... 
    public:
        ~CBase() {};
        virtual void handle() = 0;
};

class C1 : public CBase { ... something specific to C1
    public:
        virtual void handle() { do what has to be done for C1 }
};
class C2 : public CBase { ... something specific to C2
    public:
        virtual void handle() { do what has to be done for C2 }
};
```

Now, it sounds a bit like this would already solve the issue, since you can call C1.handle() or CBase->handle(). If you need it to be done through an external function, you could do:

```
void handle(CBase *base_ptr) {
    base_ptr->handle();
}
```

Personally, I find this nicer than passing by non-const reference anyways, but I know that this is a big debate.

About your SFINAE:
SFINAE just says that if the template substitution fails, the compiler will keep looking for a match and not throw an error directly. But it will throw an error if it does not find a match at all. In your case, if e.g. T = C2, it will still try to compile handle_C1(C2), which fails. (Your "if case" is a run-time decision, whereas the compiler makes these decisions at compile time)

Answer (score 0):

You could revert to the good old pointer aliasing. It is allowed to cast a pointer to a type to a pointer to another type, it is simply UB to derefence a pointer if the value pointed has not the correct type.

But here you know that at run time the type will be correct, because the `std::is_same` guarantees it. So I would write:

```
template<typename T>
void handle(T &content){

    // Initialization was done here
    if (std::is_same<C1, T>()) {
        C1* c = reinterpret_cast<C1*>(&content);
       handle_C1(*c);
    }
    if (std::is_same<C2, T>()) {
        C2* c = reinterpret_cast<C2*>(&content);
       handle_C2(*c);
    }
}
```

It just costs an automatic pointer allocation and copy that a really clever optimizing compiler could avoid because at low level machine code it is clearly a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that simply extracts the code common to both behaviors into its own function:

```
class C1 { /* ... */ };
class C2 { /* ... */ };

template<typename T>
void handle_init(T& content) {
    // Common initialization code
}

void handle(C1& c1) {
    handle_init(c1);
    // C1-specific code
}

void handle(C2& c2) {
    handle_init(c2);
    // C2-specific code
}
```

Depending on the code inside `handle_init`, the template might not be necessary if, for example, the body of the function only calls "getter" methods of `content`, which can instead be called beforehand and passed to `handle_init` by the `handle` functions.

I named both functions `handle` to be consistent with the code you provided, but you can give them different names and it will still work for most use cases. This is the case for most uses of overloading, since overload resolution uses the compile-time type of the argument, which you as the programmer usually know anyways at the invocation site.

A big exception to this is if the argument to `handle` is a template parameter, in which case you'd need to use overloading (so some of the other answers actually do require overloading because of this). Note that to call different functions based on the run-time type of an argument, overloading doesn't work and you'd need virtual methods like in Cedric's answer.

But aside from the above paragraph, there isn't really a difference in functionality between having one function that handles arguments of different types, and having different functions for each argument type. Of course, maybe in your problem domain it makes sense to think of it as the former. And calling both functions `handle` using overloading would provide a notational convenience. I just think it's good to be consciously aware of this when doing it, in case it turns out that overloading doesn't have the functionality you need.